# How to change the MAC address of pc?

Tags: networking

I am currently using ubuntu 13.04 along With windows 7. But I want to change my MAC address of pc. Is there any way to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu you can clone a Mac address in the network settings.

Click on the network icon in the top bar and select `Edit connections`. Select your current network and hit Edit. In the Ethernet tab you should see your actual device MAC and a field to enter the MAC you want to clone.

Answer (score 22):

In a command line (terminal), run:

- `sudo ifconfig eth0 down`
- `sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55`
- `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

That's sufficient for the current user's session.  However, in order for the changes to persist, you must also edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and create or modify an entry for the interface.  For example:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
     hwaddress ether 08:00:00:00:00:01
```

Source: http://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/01/11/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-an-ethernet-interface/

Comment: you should mention that we should use `sudo` before all those command

Comment: Old post but thanks. For some reason after a power outage my mac address was lost. Was able to get it from a log and set it this way - yah!

Answer (score 10):

You can install [macchanger](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/macchanger-utility-for-manipulating-the-mac-address-of-network-interfaces-included-gui-utility.html)

```
sudo apt-get install macchanger 
macchanger --mac=01:23:45:67:89:AB eth1
```