# Ethernet is connected but speed is bad.

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

I have connected my system to a particular ethernet.

The speed is very slow. But same ethernet cable if connected to some other system the speed is awesome.

I used to get same speed before. And if I connect some other ethernet the speed is awesome.

**Its just that this particular ethernet came up with slow issue with only my system** ubuntu 14.04.

Tried following commands

`sudo ifconfig down`

`sudo ifconfig up`

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: how did you measure the speed of internet? or is your speed subjective. if you did measure how much did it slow down?   its possible that that speed is limited on the machine by routers (mac address speed filtering for large bandwidth users) in which case changing the mac address may help - eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/390147/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-pc  but this is pure speculation as to cause.

Comment: Before the download speed used to be nearly 5Mbps but now its just fluctuated 10 - 30 kbps max. No setting was changed. Just one day there was no internet since moring and when the internet came back the speed of only my system reduced but same cable connected to other device returns 5mbps download speed.

Comment: My device mac address is empty and there is a selectable mac address. Which Mac address shall i clone?

Comment: Thank You very much it was the MAC address. I got the awesome speed back. Even though I don't understand what a MAC address is but thanks to you i got it working. Please add your answer to the answer section and I will make it checked

Comment: fyi:  this is a networking issue; has nothing to do with ubuntu ;  but happy to help another ubuntu user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you measure the speed of internet? or is your speed subjective. If you did measure how much did it slow down?

Its possible that that speed is limited on the machine by routers (mac address speed filtering for large bandwidth users) in which case changing the mac address may help

eg. [How to change the MAC address of pc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390147/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-pc)

but this is pure speculation as to cause.

Comment: if you're using shared internet (eg. college/university/..) its done to restrict bandwidth of 'high' users .. and you may find your new 'mac' address becomes restricted in time. the fix for this is to just pick a new mac address (mac address is the address of the card/nic (network interface card) and 'blank' just lets hardwired address get used.  as long as its unique with your network, it'll be fine so I'd just change a character or two rather than cloning another mac address.  I'm betting you could  script it to pick a new mac address each boot :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ISP is not throttling you. Sometimes ISPs throttle Bittorrent, Tor and Linux connections to prevent cybercrime.

Also, are you sure that the problem is not at the PC itself? Try connecting a wifi card or USB into the computer and compare to ethernet.