# How can I automatically change my mac address whenever my network device is up or down?

Tags: networking, network-manager, mac

[macchanger automatic script doesn’t work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFwLF.png)

I searched here before I asked and all I found was to run macchanger in **/etc/rc.local** with this simple script:

```
ifconfig enp2s0 down
macchanger -r enp2s0
ifconfig enp2s0 up
```

(I just modify eth0 cuz my device name is enp2s0)

Clearly it only setup a random mac address at startup but if I reconnect my network device it always get my real mac address so it isn’t what I was looking for.

I tried to at least leave a permanent spoofed address but [the mac spoof option in the ubuntu default network manager doesn’t do anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIOST.png), it always sent my real address.

I can’t remember exactly where but I read somewhere that it could be systemd's fault but I'm not really sure how to handle that thing or if really is its fault.

What's the right way to get a random mac address whenever I connect my network device in Ubuntu? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Since macchanger is not working as the developer clearly intended, did you file a bug report?

Comment: I was not aware but [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses) says it does not work in Jaunty (9.04). So probably it doesn't work since then?

Comment: It probably doesn't work since $IFACE doesn't return anything.

Comment: @charles-green I'm using ethernet, the only options I could find concerning MAC addresses were:
`802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             *MY REAL MAC ADDRESS*
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:`
according to the article I tried to put **stable** in **802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address** but I got an error saying that stable isn't a valid Ethernet MAC address :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from the [Gnome blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/). These settings for for Ubuntu 17.10

#### Via CLI

First, obtain the name of the wired internet connection

```
nmcli connection show
```

Secondly, set the enternet connection to generate either a "stable" or "random" address

```
nmcli connection modify "wired_connection_name" ethernet.cloned-mac-address random
```

For WiFi use `wifi.cloned-mac-address`. On network-manager 1.2.6 you'll [need to set a MAC address](https://serverfault.com/a/299563/407820) instead of `random`.

Finally, check your mac address, bring the connection down and up, and check your mac address again

```
ifconfig | grep Ether
nmcli connection down "wired_connection_name"
nmcli connection up "wired_connection_name"
ifconfig | grep Ether
```

#### Via GUI

the program `nm-connection-manager` can also be used to access this setting, bringing up a screen like the one shown below, where the drop-down box for 'Cloned MAC Address' can be changed to one of several settings.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the only solution but as I mentioned, I'm getting an error when modifying ethernet.cloned-mac-address to random it always tells me that random is not a valid MAC address.

I think it might be because the version that Ubuntu 16.04 have is the 1.2.6.

Comment: what version of network manager are you running?  `apt list network-manager`

Comment: @hola - you can peruse the nm-settings man page, and look for the cloned-mac-address in the ethernet section to see if it's valid for your version of network-manager.  It's way,way, way down in the list of possible settings.

Comment: Looks like I can only put a MAC address in there :/

Comment: @hola I'd have to run up a 16.04 VM, and poke at it's connections to try this.  Would take a while as I'd also have to download the iso first...

Comment: Looks like that's the terminal way to spoof the mac address for the Ubuntu default network manager.
I just try to spoof with a random generated one using:`nmcli connection modify "Conexión cableada 1" ethernet.cloned-mac-address CD:86:CB:35:C5:B0`
[It's here now](https://i.imgur.com/VZr4nqE.png) but like I said, it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: @Hola Perhaps it is just the newer version of nmcli that I'm running.  I used `nmcli connection modify "Conexión cableada 1" ethernet.cloned-mac-address random` and it works quite well

Comment: I'm tempted to update... I can't think of a better solution and this would be the ideal. (at least for Gnome users)
But recent Gnome versions have a really really weird breaklines in Spanish file names. They bother me too much.
Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Hola Try it in a VM first, and see if they've fixed the breaklines

Comment: On NM 1.2.6 [isn't a dropdown](https://i.imgur.com/vrEFnVt.png). Maybe [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513) or [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770611) bugs also have something to do. This one-line works also for me: `sudo sh -c 'i="wlp2s0" && macchanger $i && systemctl stop network-manager && ifconfig $i down && sleep 5 && macchanger -r $i && sleep 5 && ifconfig $i up && systemctl start && network-manager && macchanger $i'`.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this goal by a simple script that uses `ifconfig`.

Create executable script file in the directory `/etc/network/if-up.d`, thus the script will be executed each time when the command `ifup` is executed, including at system startup. Let's call the script **`mac-changer`**:

```
sudo touch /etc/network/if-up.d/mac-changer
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/mac-changer
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/mac-changer
```

- Copy the below script content and use in `nano`: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for exit.

The content of the script `mac-changer` should be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

change_mac(){
        # Prevent enless loop on error
        if (( COUNT >= 10 )); then exit 0; else COUNT=$(( COUNT + 1 )); echo "Attempt: $COUNT"; fi
        # Generate a new MAC address
        MAC="$(echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 17 | sed -r 's/(..)./\1:/g')"
        # Change the MAC address of the target network interface
        /sbin/ifconfig "$1" hw ether "${MAC}"
        # Chech whether the MAC is successfully changed anf if is not call the function again
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then change_mac; fi
        # Log the change
        echo "Interface: $1 | MAC: $MAC"
}

# Call of the function; Change 'enp0s25' with the actual interface in use; Create a log file `/tmp/mac-changer-...`
change_mac 'enp0s25' > /tmp/mac-changer-enp0s25 2>&1
```

Notes:

- In most cases, if you want, you could execute the script directly by `sudo` and the MAC address will be changed:

  ```
  sudo /etc/network/if-up.d/mac-changer
  ```
- **Please note some network interfaces do not support the MAC change feature.**

Here is the demonstration of that, how the script works:

[image]

References:

- [How to change the MAC address of pc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390147/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-pc/390182#390182)
- [Shell Programming and Scripting: how to change every 3rd character](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/46707-how-change-every-3rd-character.html)
- [How to generate a random MAC address from the Linux command line](https://serverfault.com/a/299563/364207)
- [How to check if a command succeeded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded/29379#29379)

Comment: Whenever I run:

`sudo /etc/network/if-up.d/mac-changer`

I get "Impossible to solve the host" but looks like now my address persists even when I restart the network. I'll try again on a VM.

Comment: Hi, @Hola, it is strange. The script shouldn't produce any messages, because everything is redirected to a log file - `> /tmp/mac-changer...`. Where did you get this message into the terminal or into the log file? What exactly is the message - "Impossible to solve the host" or "sudo: unable to resolve host <host-name>"?