# Internet stops working for a small interval and then restarts again

Tags: networking, firefox, internet

So, I experience this problem through Wi-fi and through Ethernet but predominantly on Ethernet.

My internet will be working fine until I try to refresh or load a new page at which point Firefox will only say "looking up .....".

The page fails to load and after a couple of minutes it loads to a screen that shows - "Server cannot be found".

The issue resolves itself in a few minutes but the problem is that downloads get interrupted and then cancelled and the wait time till the problem goes away keeps varying.

My college puts up material on its own server which I should be able to access even without internet but the issue occurs even when I try to access local IPs.

I've searched the internet looking for solutions and have found problems that look familiar, but none of the solutions given has worked for me yet.

This also isn't limited to Firefox as Steam keeps disconnecting regularly and there has also been an instance where I've typed `sudo apt-get update` and it did not connect at all.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeyUw.png)  is one instance when i tried connecting to askubuntu.com and it just got stuck at the "looking up.." phase

[Another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMbUa.png) where even connecting to addresses on the same network do not work.

Comment: Your problem may have nothing to do with Ubuntu, but be a cheap switch/router that has a failing component which fails, and its traffic stops (though regularly lights still flicker correctly, data doesn't transfer past the faulty device as it's failing to forward..) then the device resets itself & its back to normal operation (often its lights go off during it's reset). You can only detect this (if it is your problem; I'm blaming it because I've dealt with it a few times with cheap switches) by pings to devices & working out which device is the 'block' when it's down... I could also be wrong!

Comment: I live with 180 others in a hostel and all of us connect to the same Wi-Fi router and have LAN ports leading into our rooms that come from the same Gateway (10.3.1.1 it says). The thing is, no one else is experiencing any issues with their internet. I've also tried plugging into the LAN port of another room and my issue still persists.

Comment: Okay my first guess is incorrect, the next is you're being slowed by an algorithm because of excessive use, unusual traffic or some other reason I won't know. This can often be got around (*for awhile anyway*) by changing your mac address (I've pointed someone before that way before & it worked), but it's only a guess so could be wrong too, This should provide clues to investigate if this is the issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/390147/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-pc)   ps: if it works, you'll eventually become flagged again, so you change mac address again....

Comment: In a terminal window, `journalctl --follow /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will let you watch NetworManager logs as they happen.

Comment: I have had similar problems withiin the past few days, and fixed my problem by changing the DNS in my router - you could alter your network setup to use a specific nameserver rather than the defaut nameserver provided by your routers.